# Implementing ColorOcTree in OctoMap using RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am implementing a ColorOcTree in OctoMap. Since the default in OctoMap is to build a heightmap, given by this piece of code in octomap_server/src/OctomapServer.cpp in OctomapServer::publishAll(const ros::Time& rostime):

```
        //create marker:
    if (publishMarkerArray){
      unsigned idx = it.getDepth();
      assert(idx < occupiedNodesVis.markers.size());

      geometry_msgs::Point cubeCenter;
      cubeCenter.x = x;
      cubeCenter.y = y;
      cubeCenter.z = z;

      occupiedNodesVis.markers[idx].points.push_back(cubeCenter);
      if (m_useHeightMap){
        double minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ;
        m_octree->getMetricMin(minX, minY, minZ);
        m_octree->getMetricMax(maxX, maxY, maxZ);

        double h = (1.0 - std::min(std::max((cubeCenter.z-minZ)/ (maxZ - minZ), 0.0), 1.0)) *m_colorFactor;
        occupiedNodesVis.markers[idx].colors.push_back(heightMapColor(h));
      }
```

I am seeking to change the height map into a per-voxel color Octomap.

From what is stated in the paper for octomap, I can use the child class of OcTree (ColorOcTree). From what I understand, ColorOcTree contains all the methods for OcTree, plus the average color information. So, To get a colored Octomap, **rewrite OctomapServer.cpp from a OcTree based structure to an ColorOcTree structure**.

**My question is, in order to do this in OctomapServer.cpp, is this the correct method or is there some  better way to construct per-voxel colored octomap?**

---

EDIT: I finished changing OctomapServer.cpp and associated nodes to ColorOcTree, however I notice that the color information **isn't** inputted from the point cloud, as per this code in OctomapServer.cpp

It seems like it is converting a PointCloud2 cloud into a PointCloud.

```
void OctomapServer::insertCloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& cloud){
  ros::WallTime startTime = ros::WallTime::now();
  //
  // ground filtering in base frame
  //
  PCLPointCloud pc; // input cloud for filtering and ground-detection
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud, pc);
```

The second question becomes, **I need to extract RGB data from either PointCloud or PointCloud2, and have it in a float32 representation. Do I use PointXYZRGB instead of PointXYZ in reading the PointCloud (If so how?) Or is there some better way to do it?**

---

EDIT2: I did change PointXYZ to PointXYZRGB and got the associated RGB Data. however, after saving that data into the ColorOcTree and trying to send the ColorRGBA message (also in float32, I did so by dividing each one of the RGB data by 255.0) to the Occupied_cells_vis_array, I get blue color only. **Can anyone explain why it is only outputting blue voxels?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173287/implementing-coloroctree-in-octomap-using-rgbdslam/) by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-06-11**:
Isn't there a version of OctomapServer for colored maps already in RGBD-SLAM?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-06-11**:
OctomapServer is publishing blue voxels as visualization for occupied nodes by default, unless you enable the parameter for the height map coloring. Only then it will set a different color for each voxel.

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-06-11**:
Hi Armin, There is a OctomapServer for colored maps? I could not find it in the rgbdslam_freiburg directory. Can you be more specific? I realized your second comment is true, but in order to override it, is there any way? I already have extracted data from PC and i believe it is in the tree. How would I use it if I choose to modify OctomapServer.cpp? Thanks!

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-06-11**:
The line in RGBDSLAM package refers me to this repository, which is not the default repository in octomap_server (nor does the ros stack contains the color octomap nodes at all). Do you advise downloading this and using this package instead :https://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/octomap_mapping_color/?r=1940#octomap_mapping_color%2Foctomap_server%2Fsrc? This is a deprecated package.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-06-12**:
Here is a file called ColorOctomapServer.cpp in RGBDSLAM: https://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/?r=4116

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-06-12**:
That code in the branches at alufr-ros-pkg is definitely outdated though.

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-06-13**:
Thanks Armin! I just ended up rewriting OctomapServer overall. Still need to address deprecated packages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository octomap_mapping_color is mostly deprecated, thus the color octomap server wasn't usable in recent version of OctoMap. Wrote my own ColorOctomapServer.cpp and everything works.

---

Originally posted by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) with karma: 101 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20167/amine/) on 2015-02-04**:
Hello I am searching for color Octomap code in ros hydro, you have any suggestions where I can find such code? Regards